# expand wildcards in string variable

Tags: bash, wildcard, expansion

I'm reading strings from a blacklist file which contains files and folders which should get deleted. It works for simple file names, but not with wildcards.

E.g. if I type on the shell `rm -rf !(abc|def)` it deletes all but these two files. When putting this string `!(abc|def)` into blacklist it does not work, because the string does not get evaluated.

So I tried to use `eval`, but it does not work as expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
# test pattern (normally read from blacklist file)
LINE="!(abc|def)"

# output string
echo "$LINE"

# try to expand this wildcards
eval "ls $LINE"

# try with subshell
( ls $LINE )
```

How can I make this working?

Comment: ` I'm reading strings from a blacklist file ` : how ? your code doesn't show this part.

Comment: You are better off using find with -regex and -delete for this.

Comment: sjsam, i didn't show this part because it has nothing to do with my problem. I prepared a stripped down script to make it easier to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, the `extglob` shell option is turned off for non-interactive shells (like the one your script runs in).

You have to change a few things:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Turn on extglob shell option
shopt -s extglob

line='!(abc|def)'

echo "$line"

# Quoting suppresses glob expansion; this will not work
ls "$line"

# Unquoted: works!
ls $line
```

You have to

- turn on the `extglob` shell option
- use `$line` unquoted: quoting suppresses glob expansion, which is *almost always* desired, but not here

Notice that I use lowercase variable names. Uppercase is reserved for shell and environment variables; using lowercase reduces the probability of name clashes (see the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08), fourth paragraph).

Also, `eval` is not needed here.

Comment: Well this might solve the issue. However, I am curious to see how the op is reading those filenames from the blacklist file. :)

Comment: @sjsam Yes, might well be an X/Y problem ;)

Comment: You might want to mention that you can expand into a Bash array variable (e.g. `a=($line)` or iterate (portably) using `for`, but to avoid the `eval` and subshell approaches shown in the question, which lose the identity of the individual filenames.  It may also be worth some guidance on the use of `--` to avoid problems with names that look like command options, too.

Comment: You probably want to disable word splitting by setting `IFS=` as well

Comment: @chepner I agree with all of these being valid points. My answer addresses the specific problem shown in the question, as the question doesn't show how the patterns are read. While I'm all for showing best practices in answers, I don't think every answer can be a catch-all and point out things that could go wrong if the question doesn't even mention them.

Comment: @TobySpeight Previous comment also applies to your comment.